# Не отображаются картинки webpack + pug

Tags: изображения, webpack, pug

Пробую настроить webpack с pug, но почему-то не отображаются картинки на странице.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?
При чем при работе с чистым html все работает нормально и картинки показываются.
И фоны через стили тоже показываются.
Картинки в pug пробую подключать как в коде, так и через миксины:

```
include pug/libs/_libs

doctype html
html(lang="en")
  include pug/_head
  body
    h1 hello webpack
    p
      | Lorem ipsum
      span dolor
      |  sit amet.
    .block
      span.material-icons insert_emoticon
    img(src="images/choco.png" alt="choco")
    +image("choco")
```

Код миксина

```
mixin image(name)
  img.src(src=`../src/images/${name}.png` alt=name)
```

Конфигурация webpack такая:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

let mode = 'development'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  mode = 'production'
}
console.log(mode + ' mode')

module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 1500000,
    maxAssetSize: 1500000
  },
  output: {
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.pug'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          (mode === 'development') ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  ['postcss-preset-env',{}]
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|ttf|svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: './assets/fonts/[hash][ext][query]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug3-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, задачка решилась.
Оказывается просто вот так

```
img(src="images/choco.png" alt="choco")
```

вставлять изображения в код pug страницы не верно.
Нужно оборачивать путь до картинки в require() и путь должен быть полный ./images/imagename.png

```
img(src=require("./images/choco.png") alt="choco")
```

Тогда работает без copy-webpack-plugin и пр. допов с прямой вставкой или через миксины.